# Exclude elements of a list that are in another array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I'd like to create an array like this
`@exclude = ("[INFO] Reading file", "[INFO] All file(s) read");`
which contains items that I would like to ignore while looping through another array

The other array is @nyuulog which I've ready into from a file and looks similar to this:

````
[INFO] Uploading 37 article(s) from 3 file(s) totalling 23.98 MiB```
[INFO] Reading file 157.1.1.par2...
[INFO] Reading file 159.1.1.rar...
[INFO] Reading file 159.1.1.vol0+1.par2...
[INFO] All file(s) read...
[INFO] Finished uploading 23.98 MiB in 00:00:16.083 (1527.03 KiB/s). Raw upload: 2613.34 KiB/s
````

So I'm using this:

`foreach $line(@nyuulog) {print $txtfile("$line\n");}`

which writes all of the lines but I'm wanting to not write lines out to the filehandle that contains an element in the @exclude array.

Is there an easy way to do this?    I've tried numerous attempts at using grep or the new Perl ~~ command (which I don't think applies in this situation) and can't get the right combination of commands.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction - would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `next if $line =~ /\Q...\E$/` might be sufficient to skip any "progress" type lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $FilterRe = join("|", map({"(^\Q$_\E)"} @exclude));
my @Filtered = grep({!/$FilterRe/} @nyuulog);
```

Inspired by [a question on perlmonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=288854).

Comment: That did it - thank you so very much.    I have no idea what the code is doing but what I wanted ends up in @Filtered and I will take some time to go through each step to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a look-up hash for what's to be excluded, and filter the array with it

```
my %excl = map { $_ => 1 } @exclude;

my @filtered = grep { not $excl{$_} } @original;
```

This is about as efficient as list processing can be, *O(N)*, and hopefully clear and easy.

Can also have it in a `do` block to avoid an extra variable (`%excl`) floating around

```
my @filtered = do { 
    my %excl = map { $_ => 1 } @exclude;
    grep { not $excl{$_} } @original;
};
```